# Error while connecting two ROS machine to the same MASTER (one is Raspbian jessie, one is Linux in VBox)

Tags: ros, communication, ros-kinetic, machines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI everyone,
I have been trying to learn how to connect two ROS machines to the same master. I am using Linux in Virtual machine (VBox) , and raspbian jessie, and i want the master to run on the linux. what i did was both ROS are kinetic

when i run the linux, i do these steps:

1- hostname -I

*i think the first one for the Virtual machine and the second id for the main OS with is MAC OS*

```
 10.0.2.15  10.0.3.1
```

2-export ROS_IP=10.0.2.15

3-roscore

then i move to the raspbian jessie:

1- hostname -I

```
 10.0.0.8   2601:1c:8601 ......etc <<very long address with letters and numbers
```

2-export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.0.2.15:11311/

3-export ROS_IP=10.0.0.8

each machine can ping itself, but
when i ping the ROS on jessie from linux to seems to work and give me something like

```
 64 bytes from 10.0.0.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=39.868 ms
 64 bytes from 10.0.0.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=9.677 ms
 64 bytes from 10.0.0.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=38.659 ms
```

but when i ping the linux from jessie
it does not work, it fails.

so does anyone know how to solve that?

*edit 1:
when i try to run roscore on jessie it runs with master 10.0.0.8 even though i assigned export

```
 ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.0.2.15:11311/
```

so it looks that it did not get it !?

*edit2:
after running netcat i found out that the linux machine can see the raspbian but
the raspbian can not see the linux

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281084/error-while-connecting-two-ros-machine-to-the-same-master-(one-is-raspbian-jessie,-one-is-linux-in-vbox)/) by [Mohammedism](https://answers.ros.org/users/32825/mohammedism/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2018-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-28**:\

> it does not work, it fails

What does this mean? Also, being able to ping isn't sufficient. Check out http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup#Further_check:_netcat

**Comment by [Mohammedism](https://answers.ros.org/users/32825/mohammedism/) on 2018-01-28**:
it means that it says something like:
3 packet transmitted , 0 received , 100% packet loss, time 1024 ms

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-28**:
Are you setting the environment variables and running everything from the same terminal? Once you open a new terminal you have to set the environment variables all over again.

**Comment by [Mohammedism](https://answers.ros.org/users/32825/mohammedism/) on 2018-01-28**:
yes, i added them to the ~/.bashrc and i also set them manually in every terminal.

as i said some machine A sees B
bug B does not see A
or at least this is what i understood

is it possible the problem is that the linux in running in virtual machine?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-28**:
Yes, that does change things. Definitely update and retag your question indicating that you're using a virtual machine.

**Comment by [Mohammedism](https://answers.ros.org/users/32825/mohammedism/) on 2018-01-28**:
oh thanks for the notes, i will update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's look like a problem with vbox network configuration, the vbox create a subnet inside the computer and to access from outside you need to configure the vbox. Try following this [tutorial](https://2buntu.com/articles/1513/accessing-your-virtualbox-guest-from-your-host-os/).

---

Originally posted by [rdelgadov](https://answers.ros.org/users/33433/rdelgadov/) with karma: 51 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohammedism](https://answers.ros.org/users/32825/mohammedism/) on 2018-01-29**:
thanks man, i figured out what was the problem. I had my network attached to NAT which will use the main machine ip address, with an extension, which wont work. so i had to attach my virtual machine to bridget wifi adaptor, which will give the VM separate ip